# Arduino отправляет лишний символ

Tags: arduino

Есть такой код:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.print("Start");

}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available() > 0){
    int in_data = Serial.read();
    Serial.println(in_data);
    Serial.println("----");
  }
}
```

Он принимает символы и отправляет обратно их коды. Но помимо кода отправленного символа он отправляет еще число 10, если я правильно понимаю, то находит где-то перевод строки. Вот пример вывода если отправить ардуино букву `z`.

```
122
----
10
----
```

проблема легко решается одним if, но мне все-таки интересно узнать причину, почему ардуино находит лишний символ. У ютубера у которого я смотрю ролик все нормально работает.

У меня `arduino uno`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В настройках Монитора выберите вариант "Нет конца строки".
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]